# Dynamically add images jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have an array of images and then I iterate through each using $.each but I can't get the images to show on the page, it ends up with nothing getting showed.

```
<ul id="imagesList">
  <li>No images found</li>
</ul>

$(function(){
            //load image array
            var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'};
            $.each(images, function(){
               $('#imagesList').appendTo('<li>' + this + '</li>'); 
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Use `append`:

```
$.each(images, function(){
    $('#imagesList').append('<li><img src="' + this + '" /></li>'); 
});
```

Or, if you insist on using `appendTo`:

```
$.each(images, function(){
    $('<li><img src="' + this + '" /></li>').appendTo('#imagesList'); 
});
```

If you want to show a loader while the image is loading, use this:

```
var $list = $('#imagesList');

$.each(images, function(i, src) {
    var $li = $('<li class="loading">').appendTo($list);

    $('<img>').appendTo($li).one('load', function() {
        $li.removeClass('loading');
    }).attr('src', src);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyar1u7a/1/

Comment: duh! using it the other way arround. I feel stupid haha, thanks!

Comment: @JosephSilber is there a way to add loader to these loaded images?

Comment: @JosephSilber thanks, will check it out I have made a workaround though .. http://greencool.co/green_cool_final/products/

Answer (score -1):

There is little issue with your appendTo function. You are using it in wrong way.

Please try below code..

```
<ul id="imagesList">
  <li>No images found</li>
</ul>
$(function(){
            //load image array
            var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'};
            $.each(images, function(){
               $('<li>' + this + '</li>').appendTo('#imagesList'); 
            });
        });
```