# jQuery: Fill array with images from a folder. or use AJAX to load images from a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to dynamically insert the images inside a folder into an array to be used as a thumbnail.

I have read some questions like this one.

[Dynamically add images jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230579/dynamically-add-images-jquery)

However, what I want to do is not to declare the content of the array.

I don't want to do it this way

```
var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'}
```

instead what I want is

```
var images = [];
```

and then I want to fill the array, or possibly JSON when the page loads.

I've read that I can use AJAX but I do not how to use it. so if array is possible please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the source for this data? Need to start there to create array

Comment: This one is the actual directory C:\Users\MicahAaron.CMPHIL\Desktop\Aaron\Bootstrap-Image-Gallery-3.1.1\img
Then from there, I want to get all the images from the folder to insert it into to the array. I've tried to use AJAX using the directory as the url. But it doesn't work

Comment: You need server code to pull the file names from the directory. WHat server language are you using?

Comment: I'm using none, just client-side JS and  jQuery. Is it possible for AJAX to load these images that I want from my local folder?

Comment: You can't access file system using javascript in browser

Comment: Guess I'll have to upload them to flickr then. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

To load files from a directory check this [HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) tutorial.